# Exposing ClientBase<T>'s internal proxy interface

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm consider wrapping `ClientBase<T>` in a wrapper that does nothing more than expose the proxy interface (the T part).

I'm trying to think of the possible repercussions of doing this.  Obviously, the framework developers made the interface protected for a reason.  The only thing I can think of is that it is possible for someone to directly call Close or other ICommunicationObject methods on it by casting it to an ICommunicationObject.

The reason I wish to do this is to take advantage of `ClientBase<T>`'s ChannelFactory caching with a nice default implementation that I do not have to maintain.

We don't like using the auto generated proxies by svcutil or visual studio, since these also tend to generate extra overhead with intermediate classes for transfer.  Our services are all .NET on both sides, and we control both ends and do not need wsdl, discovery, or other features that svcutil generates from, and we don't want to write wrapper methods for everything when the interface is available right there.  We want to use the exact same interface on both sides of the connection, rather than having to maintain two copies of different interfaces that look the same.

One of the biggest advantages of this approach is that if we make a change to the interface, we need only recompile the app, and not regenerate the proxy for every client that uses it.  (assuming the change doesn't break any existing usage, for instance merely adding a property or method that doesn't otherwise change the behavior of the existing properties and methods).  Yes, I know we should probably be versioning our interfaces.. but that's an option as well.

Can anyone think of any other problems we might face by doing this?  Can you think of a different way to achieve what we want without writing our own client wrapper?

EDIT:

Interesting, I found a CodeProject article that basically does what i'm suggesting here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412363/How-to-Use-a-WCF-Service-without-Adding-a-Service

Still looking a good reason NOT to do this.